# Supply chain contract cannot pay

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a supply chain contract and the basic idea is:
in itemManger contract:

1. create an item where input string and uint. For example, "Iphone", 123.
2. input 0 into item function
3. 

> 0:
> address: _item 0x5C9eb5D6a6C2c1B3EFc52255C0b356f116f6f66D
> 1:
> string: _identifier Iphone
> 2:
> uint256: _itemPrice 123
> 3:
> uint8: _state 0

In item contract:
there is a payment function where I input 123 so that i paid all the price and could trigger the delivery back to itemManager contract.

The error I got is when I pay 123 wei:

> from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: Item.(receive) 0x5C9...6f66Dvalue: 123 weidata: 0xlogs: 0hash: 0xb9f...3ff87
> transact to Item.(receive) errored: VM error: revert.
> revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Reason provided by the contract: "The transaction wasn't successful, canceling".
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

The code is :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Item {
    uint public priceInWei;
    uint public pricePaid;
    uint public index;
    
    ItemManager parentContract;
    
    constructor(ItemManager _parentContract, uint _priceInWei, uint _index) public {
        priceInWei = _priceInWei;
        index = _index;
        parentContract = _parentContract;
    }
    
    receive() external payable {
        require(pricePaid == 0, "Item is paid already");
        require(priceInWei == msg.value, "Only full payments allowed");
        pricePaid += msg.value;
        (bool success, ) = address(parentContract).call{value:msg.value}(abi.encodeWithSignature("triggerPayment(uint256)"));
        require(success, "The transaction wasn't successful, canceling");
        
    }
    
    fallback() external payable {
        
    }
}

contract ItemManager {
    
    enum SupplyChainState{Created, Paid, Delivered}
    
    struct S_Item {
        Item _item;
        string _identifier;
        uint _itemPrice;
        ItemManager.SupplyChainState _state;
        
    }
    
    mapping(uint => S_Item) public items;
    uint itemIndex;
    
    event SupplyChainStep(uint _itemIndex, uint _step, address _itemAddress);
    
    function createItem(string memory _identifier, uint _itemPrice) public {
        Item item = new Item(this, _itemPrice, itemIndex);
        items[itemIndex]._item = item;
        items[itemIndex]._identifier = _identifier;
        items[itemIndex]._itemPrice = _itemPrice;
        items[itemIndex]._state = SupplyChainState.Created;
        
        emit SupplyChainStep(itemIndex, uint (items[itemIndex]._state), address(item));
        itemIndex++;
        
    }
    
    function triggerPayment(uint _itemIndex) public payable {
        require(items[_itemIndex]._itemPrice == msg.value, "Only full payments accepted");
        require(items[_itemIndex]._state == SupplyChainState.Created, "Item is further in the chain");
        items[_itemIndex]._state = SupplyChainState.Paid;
        
        emit SupplyChainStep(_itemIndex, uint (items[_itemIndex]._state), address(items[_itemIndex]._item));
    }
    
    function triggerDelivery(uint _itemIndex) public {
        require(items[_itemIndex]._state == SupplyChainState.Paid, "Item is further in the chain");
        items[_itemIndex]._state = SupplyChainState.Delivered;
        
        emit SupplyChainStep(itemIndex, uint(items[itemIndex]._state), address(items[_itemIndex]._item));

    }
    
}
```

I am a beginner on solidity and I do not understand where goes wrong. Please help thx

Comment: Have u written this contract?

Comment: Try to write another function and not use the default receive, and then call it and see if its work :/

Comment: You're using remix did you try to debug the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is an outdated version of an example code in an Udemy course. The course author has provided a [newer version](https://ethereum-blockchain-developer.com/050-supply-chain-project/02-item-smart-contract/).